# Stokes' Theorem Explanation

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, definition, intuition

Can someone explain what Stokes' Theorem is measuring? What would taking the integral of a vector on a surface give you? When would you use it?

This is the only definition I have and I don't really understand what it's saying.

> Let $S$ be an oriented smooth surface that is bounded by a simple, closed, smooth boundary curve $C$ with positive orientation. Also let $\vec{F}$ be a vector field then,
>
> $$\int\limits_C \vec{F} \cdot d\vec{r} =
> \iint\limits_S \mathrm{curl}\ \vec{F} \cdot d\vec{S}$$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While I can't do it justice, this video done by Khan Academy was invaluable to me. I hope you find it useful as well:

[Stokes' theorem intuition](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/multivariable-calculus/greens-theorem-and-stokes-theorem/stokes-theorem/v/stokes-theorem-intuition)

Comment: That helps, thank you!

Comment: Yep, the best explanation you'll ever get on the internet is there :)

Comment: That's a good video, but I don't think it explains why the quantity $\nabla \times F$ measures how much the vector field $F$ is "curling" at a given point.

Answer (score 0):

The spirit of this theorem is still about the meaning of $\nabla \times F$.

To realize this you can see the explanation in the textbook of Thomas Calculus, or see the following image of my brief note.

Circulation density (curl dot k)
[image: Circulation density (curl dot k)]

Curl in 3D
[image: Curl in 3D]

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Thanks! I'll learn more about it.